# How to link websiteurl in anchor tag in jsp page

Tags: jsp

in my localhost it is working. but in my site **www.step2java.com** the **Java Core** link not working. 
 in my public_html after deploying they put the Project rootfolder like Step2java.   plz tell me how to solve. I m only using jsp and jquery

### web.xml

```
 <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@include file="/jsp/menu.jsp" %>
<%@include file="/navigation-left/nav_home.jsp" %>
<%@include file="/containerPage/container_Home.jsp" %>
<div class="navigation-right"> </div>
```

### menu.jsp

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/style.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/js_library/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/js_library/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/navigation.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="header"><div class="container">
<div id="header-logo"> <a title="step2java.com" href="#"><div ><img  style="border: 0 none;height: auto;max-width: 34%;vertical-align: middle;"alt="" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/images/logo.jpg" ></div> </a></div>
<h1 style="margin-top: 43px;">Step2Java</h1>
</div></div>
<div id="menu"><div class="container">
<ul><li class="menu-allround"> <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>">Home</a></li><li class="menu-allround"> <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/javaHome.jsp">Java Core</a></li><li class="menu-allround"> <a href="#">Spring</a></li><li class="menu-topround"> <a href="#">Hibernate</a><div class="dropdown" id="hibernate-menu"><div class="tut-title">Hibernate Tutorials</div><div class="dropdown-item"> <div>1. <a href="#">Hibernate Core</a></div></div></div></li><li class="menu-topround"> <a href="#">Others</a><div class="dropdown" id="misc-menu"><div class="dropdown-item"><ol><li><a href="#">Java MongoDB</a></li><li><a href="#">jUnit</a></li><li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li></ol></div></div></li></ul>

</div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You should update your original question with more info rather than adding the same question again.

Comment: Second question has more no of code with more data

Comment: Still i m not getting any good answers